# Classifying anger,disgust,fear,joy,sadness,surprise using RTextTools

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, tm

I have trying to do sentiment analysis of tweets. I am trying to classify anger,disgust,fear,joy,sadness,surprise of those tweets which is generally done by RTextTools. But I can't how to do it? It would helpful if anyone would help.

Any way of doing it would help. I am not trying to achieve positive or negative categorization. Which i have successfully done.

Similar categorization can be done in sentiment R package. But only Bayes Algorithm can be used. It is also okay if I can apply other Algorithms in the classify_emotion() of sentiment package.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you want an answer will the complete code to your analysis? Have you already written the script to load the tweets of your interest?

Comment: yes i have loaded the tweets. I have used sentiment package to find sentiment but it uses Bayes Algorithm and I want to change the algorithm. I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the caret package (http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html). What you are trying to do are two different classifications (one mulit-class and one two class problem). Represent the document as term frequency vectors and run a classification algorithm of your choice. SVMs usually work well with bag of words approaches.

You would need some training data of course, but there are data sets available. https://www.crowdflower.com/data-for-everyone/